# Disable laptop lid sleep

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, laptop, suspend, lid

Xubuntu 14.04. I've already done the following:

- ```
  HandleLidSwitch=ignore
  LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
  ```
- ```
  xset -dpms
  ```
- disabled xfce power manager in session and start up
- set power settings to do nothing when the lid is closed

I've not yet disabled ACPI in grub but that's my next step I guess. This problem just occurred after running updates.

I DO NOT want this laptop to sleep when the lid is dropped since it's for playing music via Pithos and has media buttons on the outside so I can control it with the lid down. I had TLP installed, I've uninstalled it.

If disabling ACPI in grub doesn't stop this then I'll have to take the magnet out of the lid that tells the hardware the lid is down. This is very very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disable ACPI. ACPI is used for many other things including temperature and fan so I would not recommend disabling it.

Go into your BIOS settings and change the setting there if that's the problem.

Comment: It never had this issue prior to running updates, no change made in bios and a 12.04 install on the same laptop does not sleep when the lid is dropped. This IS strictly a 14.04 issue, and I need 14.04 to run the most current version of Pithos which is the only version that works with Pandora. I need to fix this, but how? Something in recent updates has made power manager settings ineffective, possibly in a newer kernel? Do I just wait and hope? I don't think I know enough technical information to make a bug report.

Comment: @user299954 There's no doubt I believe you made no changes to your BIOS. However, did you even check to see what the settings are? It could be that 14.04 is communicating with the BIOS settings where 12.04 wasn't. I'm just saying if you haven't checked, you should because it *is* possible. I might be wrong but I thought that's what ACPI was supposed to do (communicate with BIOS settings)

Comment: I just noticed my other laptop is now doing the same thing, sleeping when the lid is dropped. They're two totally different sets of hardwares. I checked in BIOS on the one I need to never sleep with the lid down and there's nothing in BIOS about lid behavior that I can find. Just battery info, charging info, cpu power states, pci/usb power states, screen brightness, and when power is considered critical and things like that which are only in play when the OS doesn't support them. It's a Centrino based laptop with a Pentium M, an old Dell Inspiron 6000. As I said, prior to some recent updates i

Comment: Prior to some recent updates it never slept when the lid was dropped, the only recent change to the system before the problem happened were running updates. I thought that perhaps TLP was at issue and so I uninstalled it, then after trying other things that have been suggested elsewhere, nothing worked, so I thought I should do a clean install and start with a clean slate. Is there a way to uninstall updates? I could remove them one by one to see where it starts to work again and then submit a bug report for that specific update.